# porque cuando hago una conexión php a base de datos utilizando mysqli orientada a objetos esta me exige usar variables como $conn y $connex?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysqlconnector

cuando hago conexiones orientadas a objetos en php esta me exige usar variables como "$conn" para enlazar la conexion y "Connex" para hacer otras operaciones , si hubiera algún manual que explique esto, y porque no puedo usar otras variables que no sean esas.

esta es mi clase conexión:

```html
<?php 

    class Conexion
    {
     private $servername = "localhost";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $bd="text_data";
        private $conn;

        function openConexion()
        {
            $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password,$this->bd);
            return $conn;
        }
        function closeConexion()
        {
            $this->conn->close();
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Esta es mi clase de consultas de datos:

```html
<?php 
 
require 'Conexion.php';


 class savedata
 {
  private $conexion;
  function __construct()
  {
   $this->conexion=new Conexion();
  }
  public function saveData($idMac)
  {
   $connex = $this->conexion->openConexion();
   $f=$connex->query("SELECT * FROM datos"); 
   //$t=$f->fetch_array();
   echo " numeros =".$f->num_rows;
   $connex ->close(); 
  }
  
 }
 
 ?>
```

Comment: añade el código involucrado, para mirar el escenario, pues te aclara desde aquí que eso no es necesario

Comment: todo esta bien , pero no encuentro una explicacion porque si cambio las variables en la conexión el "$conn" por otra como por ejemplo "$miconexion" esta me informa que deba usar el "$conn" solamente , lo mismo pasa en mi otra clase cuando utilizo otra envés de "$connex"  otra como por ejemplo "$recibirCone" esta me pide que utilice exclusivamente  el "connex"

Comment: añade le mensaje donde te indica eso que dices